# bootstrap 4 scss: how to mixin the bootstrap's pb-x pm-x values to custom class?

Tags: css, sass, bootstrap-4

I want to remove pb-x and pm-x classes from there:

```
<div class="my-title pb-4 pm-4"> ... </div>
```

and include them to `my-title` defined in my scss that imports bootsrap's functions, variables, mixins:

Something like:

```
.my-title{
    @include pb-4;
    @include mb-4;
}
```

But the problem is that there are no such mixins (BS publish some classes as mixins but not this time).

Spacings pb-x pm-x are created there: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/scss/utilities/_spacing.scss

And it looks like I need to access $spacers array and reference 4th element? How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Since `$spacers` was conveniently defined in bs _variables.css   I've found that my goal can be achieved using:

```
.my-title {
    // ...
    padding-bottom: map-get($spacers, 3); // .pb-3
    margin-bottom: map-get($spacers, 4); // .pm-4
}
```

Additionally custom mixins (pb-3) or placeholders (%pb-3) classes could be created using this way. I like to extend bs with missing classes that publish theirs variables (e.g. input color is missed) but this time I stay with simple `map-get($spacers, 3)`

Answer (score 1):

Did you try `@extend` ? Not sure if the below code serves your purpose.

```
.my-title{
    @extend .pb-4;
    @extend .pm-4;
}
```

How have you imported bootstrap in the scss file where you define **.my-title** ? 
Suppose you define **.my-title** in index.scss file.

You can then import bootstrap at the top of **index.scss** file using

```
@import "path/to/bootstrap.css";
```

If including `.css` file do not work, try renaming `bootstrap.css` to `bootstrap.scss`. This will surely work. Now you can ommit the `.scss` extension from import, if you want.

```
@import "path/to/bootstrap";
```

Comment: Thank you, I have read several articles that do not recommend to use extend because of css code generation specific. But I will experiment with it.

Comment: A very valid point. `@extend` is supposed to be used only with placeholder-classes and not actual classes.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `@extend` instead of `@import`. There is no `pm-4` class in Bootstrap. Did you mean `mb-4`?

```
.my-title{
    @extend .pb-4;
    @extend .mb-4;
}
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/4jpl7TRudJ